# Azure Search - phonetic search implementation

Tags: azure, elasticsearch, lucene, azure-cognitive-search

I was trying out Phoenetic search using Azure Search without much luck. My objective is to work out an Index configuration that can handle typos and accomodate phonetic search for end users.

With the below configuration and sample data, I was trying to search for intentionally misspelled words like 'softvare' or 'alek'. I got results for 'alek' thanks for Phonetic analyzer; but didn't get any results for 'softvare'.

Looks like for this requirement phonetic search will not do the trick.

Only option that I found was to use synonyms map. The major pitfall is that I'm unable to use the Phonetics / Custom analyzer along with Synonyms :(

What are the various strategies that you would recommend for taking care of typos?

### search query used

1. `?api-version=2017-11-11&search=alec`
2. `?api-version=2017-11-11&search=softvare`

### Here is the index configuration

```
 "name": "phonetichotels",  
 "fields": [
   {"name": "hotelId", "type": "Edm.String", "key":true, "searchable": false},
   {"name": "baseRate", "type": "Edm.Double"},
   {"name": "description", "type": "Edm.String", "filterable": false, "sortable": false, "facetable": false, "analyzer":"my_standard"},
   {"name": "hotelName", "type": "Edm.String", "analyzer":"my_standard"},
   {"name": "category", "type": "Edm.String", "analyzer":"my_standard"},
   {"name": "tags", "type": "Collection(Edm.String)", "analyzer":"my_standard"},
   {"name": "parkingIncluded", "type": "Edm.Boolean"},
   {"name": "smokingAllowed", "type": "Edm.Boolean"},
   {"name": "lastRenovationDate", "type": "Edm.DateTimeOffset"},
   {"name": "rating", "type": "Edm.Int32"},
   {"name": "location", "type": "Edm.GeographyPoint"}
  ],
```

### Analyzer (part of the index creation)

```
"analyzers":[
    {
      "name":"my_standard",
      "@odata.type":"#Microsoft.Azure.Search.CustomAnalyzer",
      "tokenizer":"standard_v2",
      "tokenFilters":[ "lowercase", "asciifolding", "phonetic" ]
    }
  ]
```

### Analyze API Input and Output for 'software'

```
{
     "analyzer":"my_standard",
     "text": "software"
  }

{
    "@odata.context": "https://ctsazuresearchpoc.search.windows.net/$metadata#Microsoft.Azure.Search.V2017_11_11.AnalyzeResult",
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "SFTW",
            "startOffset": 0,
            "endOffset": 8,
            "position": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

### Analyze API Input and Output for 'softvare'

```
{
     "analyzer":"my_standard",
     "text": "softvare"
  }

{
    "@odata.context": "https://ctsazuresearchpoc.search.windows.net/$metadata#Microsoft.Azure.Search.V2017_11_11.AnalyzeResult",
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "SFTF",
            "startOffset": 0,
            "endOffset": 8,
            "position": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

### Sample data that I loaded

```
{
         "@search.action": "upload",
         "hotelId": "5",
         "baseRate": 199.0,
         "description": "Best hotel in town for software people",
         "hotelName": "Fancy Stay",
         "category": "Luxury",
         "tags": ["pool", "view", "wifi", "concierge"],
         "parkingIncluded": false,
         "smokingAllowed": false,
         "lastRenovationDate": "2010-06-27T00:00:00Z",
         "rating": 5,
         "location": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [-122.131577, 47.678581] }
       },
{
         "@search.action": "upload",
         "hotelId": "6",
         "baseRate": 79.99,
         "description": "Cheapest hotel in town ",
         "hotelName": " Alec Baldwin Motel",
         "category": "Budget",
         "tags": ["motel", "budget"],
         "parkingIncluded": true,
         "smokingAllowed": true,
         "lastRenovationDate": "1982-04-28T00:00:00Z",
         "rating": 1,
         "location": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [-122.131577, 49.678581] }
       },
```

With the right configuration, I should have got results even with the misspelled words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you could read in my post; my Objective was to handle the typos.

The only easy option is to use the inbuilt Lucene functionality - Fuzzy Search. I'm yet to check on the response times as the querytype has to be set to 'full' for using fuzzy search. Otherwise, the results were satisfactory.

Example: 
`search=softvare~&fuzzy=true&querytype=full`
will return all documents with the 'Software' in it.

For further reading please go through [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/lucene-query-syntax-in-azure-search#bkmk_fuzzy)

Answer (score 2):

I work on Azure Search. Before I suggest approaches to handle misspelled words, it would be helpful to look at your custom analyzer (my_standard) configuration.   It might tell us why it's not able to handle the case for 'softvare'.  As a DIY, you can use the [Analyze API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/test-analyzer) to see the tokens created using your custom analyzer and it should contain 'software' to actually match the docs.

Now then, here are a few ways that can be used independently or in conjunction to handle misspelled words. The best approach varies depending on the use-case and I strongly suggest you experiment with these to figure out the best one in your case.

1. You are already familiar with phonetic filters which is a common approach to handle similarly pronounced terms. If you haven't already, try different encoders for the filter to evaluate which configuration gives you the best results. Check out the list of encoders [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/custom-analyzers-in-azure-search#token-filters-reference).
2. Use fuzzy queries supported as part of the Lucene query syntax in Azure Search which returns terms that are near the original query term based on a distance metric. The limitation here is that it works on a single term. Check the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/lucene-query-syntax-in-azure-search#bkmk_fuzzy) for more details. Sample query would look like - `search=softvare~1` You can also use term boosting to give the original term more boost in cases where the original term is also a valid term.
3. You also alluded to synonyms which is also used to query with misspelled terms. This approach gives you the most control over the process of handling typos but also require you to have prior knowledge of different typos for terms. You can use these [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-synonyms) if you want to experiment with synonyms.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have updated the post with the details that you have asked for. The analyze API output is not behaving the way you were mentioning though. Regarding the other options - I'll go through and try the other encoders; but Fuzzy is not helping; and synonyms and phonetics doesn't seem to be going hand in hand (refer to the other post that i created related to this issue [Link] (https://stackoverflow.com/q/54576138/10142703)  )