# Can we use Phonetic token and Synonyms together?

Tags: azure, elasticsearch, solr, lucene

I am trying to enable phonetic analyzer, and synonyms together. It doesn't seem to work. Is it wrong to use them together?

In the below implementation I would expect the search query be converted using synonyms and then phonetic analyzer be used to retrieve the results. But my synonyms are totally ignored in here.

If i remove the phonetic analyser as part of the index creation, then the synonyms are working fine.

Also, the synonyms work fine if i use the in built analyzers like `en.microsoft`; instead of custom analyzers. Is this a bug?

### My Synonym map

```
{   
   "name":"mysynonymmap",   
   "format":"solr", 
   "synonyms": "    
    SW, Software, Softvare, software, softvare, sft\n   
    HW, Hardware, Hardvare, hardware, hardvare, hdw => hardware\n"  
}
```

### Below is how the index is getting created

`````
     "name": "newphonetichotelswithsynonyms",  
     "fields": [
       {"name": "hotelId", "type": "Edm.String", "key":true, "searchable": false},
       {"name": "baseRate", "type": "Edm.Double"},
       {"name": "description", "type": "Edm.String", "filterable": false, "sortable": false, "facetable": false, "analyzer":"my_standard",  
        "synonymMaps":[ 
            "mysynonymmap"  
        ]},
       {"name": "hotelName", "type": "Edm.String", "analyzer":"my_standard",    
        "synonymMaps":[ 
            "mysynonymmap"  
        ]},
       {"name": "category", "type": "Edm.String", "analyzer":"my_standard", 
        "synonymMaps":[ 
            "mysynonymmap"  
        ]},
       {"name": "tags", "type": "Collection(Edm.String)", "analyzer":"my_standard", 
        "synonymMaps":[ 
            "mysynonymmap"  
        ]},
       {"name": "parkingIncluded", "type": "Edm.Boolean"},
       {"name": "smokingAllowed", "type": "Edm.Boolean"},
       {"name": "lastRenovationDate", "type": "Edm.DateTimeOffset"},
       {"name": "rating", "type": "Edm.Int32"},
       {"name": "location", "type": "Edm.GeographyPoint"}
      ],
  "analyzers":[
    {
      "name":"my_standard",
      "@odata.type":"#Microsoft.Azure.Search.CustomAnalyzer",
      "tokenizer":"standard_v2",
      "tokenFilters":[ "lowercase", "asciifolding", "phonetic" ]
    }
  ]
     }````
`````

Comment: Synonyms has to be applied before the phonetic filter runs, since you'd otherwise have to match your synonyms to the phonetic spelling. I'm not familiar with Azure Search, so I have no idea how you'd do that, but that's the issue at least :-)

Comment: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/create-index)

Comment: The documentation doesn't seem to say anything about the order in which these attributes need to be applied. [Documentation Link] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/create-index). Also, in my specific example, I'm not expecting both of them to play a role. Example: When I'm searching for 'softvare' only the synonym maps will come to play not the phonetics. Was your comment based on Lucene? I can go through their documentation for reference

Comment: Think about it this way - each filter works with the result of the previous filter. Otherwise it'd be hard to reason about what the end result would be. When the phonetic filter is applied, it converts the input token to a phonetic version of the same token (i.e. "traffic" could be converted to "trafik" or something similar). After the token has been converted to its phonetic counterpart, it'll no longer map to the synonyms you've defined (unless you defined a synonym for "trafik") and no synonym expansion can take place.

Comment: If you want to have different behavior, define two fields - one for phonetic search and one with synonyms expanded. That also allow you to weigh the different fields differently, scoring phonetic hits lower.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions @MatsLindh! The second option works as expected; but not sure if it makes sense as I'll be duplicating the data. Will try your first option as well.

Comment: Since you'll be searching the data different ways (and filters are a lossy process), you probably want to store it twice. You don't have to configure the field as stored, as you only need the tokens - that should at least limit the storage requirement slightly.